# Welcher Satz ist richtig? "für jeden den" oder "für jeden der"

Tags: grammatical-case, conjunction, accusative

Ich weiß, dass der Akkusativ den Artikel verändert, das Adjektiv und manchmal auch den Namen. Aber ich bin mir unsicher über die Konjunktion, wenn wir schon ein Pronomen (z.B jeder) verändert haben.

> Nennen Sie die Namen und schreiben Sie für jeden den markiert ist.

oder:

> Nennen Sie die Namen und schreiben Sie für jeden der markiert ist.

oder vielleicht könnten wir einfach sagen:

> Nennen Sie die Namen und schreiben Sie für jeden dass markiert ist.

---

And the expression I wanted to say was: " try to mention names (of objects) that have been marked (in the picture).

Comment: Die Sätze machen wenig Sinn. "...schreiben Sie für jeden den/der/dass markiert ist"? Ich verstehe die Frage anhand dieser Beispiele leider nicht.

Comment: Es klingt, als wäre der Satz eigentlich länger. Kannst Du vielleicht auf einer anderen Sprache sagen, was Du ausdrücken möchtest?

Comment: Leibe(r) @Olafant wir haben es verbessert, was denken Sie jetzt?

Comment: I just don't know which one is correct and the best expression among those three sentences.

Comment: None of it is correct. It just doesn't make sense. Can you add some context?

Comment: And the expression I wanted to say was: " try to mention names (of objects) that have been marked (in the picture).

Comment: Is there anyone to tell me the answer?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Sätze funktionieren so leider nicht. Die Aufgabe könnte etwa lauten:

> Schreiben Sie zu jedem der markierten Objekte den Namen auf.

oder

> Schreiben Sie für jedes der (im Bild) markierten Objekte den Namen auf.

Comment: Danke liebe(r) @Olafant , then "Schreiben Sie für jedes im Bild der markierten Objekte den Namen auf." ist richtig?

Comment: No. ... für jedes der Objekte ... für jedes der markierten Objekte ... für jedes der im Bild markierten Objekte.

Comment: Aha! danke! jetzt habe ich es verstanden!

Comment: @Olafant Since your comment helped the OP to understand, I think you should incorporate it to your answer :)